# SQLAlchemy eager loading recursive model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, eager-loading

How can you write the model that it eager loads the parents and children of a certain role recursively. So not only the child of the role you are fetching now but also it's children.

Do you risk ending in an infinite loop or does SQLAlchemy have the logic to detect these?

The SQLAlchemy model is as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


roles_parents = Table(
'roles_parents', Base.metadata,
Column('role_id', Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id')),
Column('parent_id', Integer, ForeignKey('roles.id'))
)


Base = declarative_base()
class Role(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'roles'

id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String(20))
parents = relationship(
    'Role',
    secondary=roles_parents,
    primaryjoin=(id == roles_parents.c.role_id),
    secondaryjoin=(id == roles_parents.c.parent_id),
    backref=backref('children', lazy='joined'),
    lazy='joined'
)

def get_children(self):
    logger.log_dbg("get_children(self) with name: "  + self.name)
    for child in self.children:
        yield child
        for grandchild in child.get_children():
            yield grandchild

@staticmethod
def get_by_name(name):
    logger.log_dbg("get_by_name( " + name + " )")
    with DBManager().session_scope() as session:
        role = session.query(Role).options(joinedload(
            Role.children).joinedload(Role.parents)).filter_by(
            name=name).first()
        # role = session.query(Role).filter_by(name=name).first()
        session.expunge_all()
        return role
```

You can see that I tried to enable eager loading on the parents relationship via an attribute in the relationship and via options in the query where I fetch a Role.

The reason for needing this eager load (and session.expunge_all()), is that the session is lost when trying to get the child via get_children().

Due to the eager load, get_children no longer fails when accessing the child role of this role. However, it still fails when trying to fetch the grandchild. So eager loading seems to work for the child role but does not eager load its children.

Comment: There is a github repository [hierarchical-data](https://github.com/sohaibfarooqi/hierarchical-data) that provides several options of reading and writing parent-child related models using Flask and SQLALchemy.

Comment: I'm going to have a look

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/sqlalchemy/lUhCDfkPc9k/hlExoZNBjSwJ):

```
def recursive_expunge(obj, dbSession):
    def _recursive_expunge(_obj):
        _instance_state = sqlalchemy.inspection.inspect(_obj)
        if _instance_state.detached or _instance_state.transient:
          return
        _mapper = _instance_state.mapper
        try:
            dbSession.expunge(_obj)
        except sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError:
            pass
        except sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError:
            pass
        if _mapper:
            _loaded_rels = [i for i in _mapper.relationships.items() if i[0] not in _instance_state.unloaded]
            for (_name, _rel) in _loaded_rels:
                _loaded_rel_data = getattr(_obj, _name)
                if _loaded_rel_data:
                    if not _rel.uselist:
                        _recursive_expunge(_loaded_rel_data)
                    else:
                        for _i in _loaded_rel_data:
                            _recursive_expunge(_i)
    _recursive_expunge(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious as to why you'd want to eagerly load grandchildren as well: what's the use case?

The reason I'm asking this, is I'm assuming you'd be able to access the grandchildren when needed, by accessing the `.children` property on the current children nodes. This should reduce the memory load (by not loading all children recursively), and also make processing the current node (role) easier to reason about.

Comment: The session is lost in the RBAC flask alchemy module. It might be seen as a design flaw of the RBAC module. I have to return a role object and best practice is to not keep the session open if you are not able to close it with certainty some time later. Since I pass the object on to the module, I am not in control of closing the session. So I close it directly after fetching the object. But then the RBAC code is not able to access children if they are not eager loaded.